# Get the remaining rows

Tags: mysql, sql

See the SQL query below, it count the total records that match with `numbers` and `business` tables.

```
SELECT N.mobile, B.name, count(*) as Total FROM records as R
 LEFT JOIN business as B ON B.id = R.business_id
 LEFT JOIN numbers as N ON N.id  = R.numbers_id 
group by N.mobile, B.name
```

However, there are remaining rows (`N.mobile, B.name`) that are not included in the result, how to include them and the `Total` would be 0?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear - could you post an example of the table data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saying that there are `business` and `numbers` rows that don't have an entry in `records`, but you want to include them in the count?  Since MySQL doesn't support a `FULL OUTER JOIN` use `UNION` to get the results you want:

```
SELECT N.mobile, B.name, count(*) as Total FROM records as R
LEFT JOIN business as B ON B.id = R.business_id
LEFT JOIN numbers as N ON N.id  = R.numbers_id 
GROUP BY N.mobile, B.name

UNION

SELECT N.mobile, NULL, 0
FROM numbers AS N
LEFT JOIN records as R ON N.id = R.numbers_id
WHERE r.numbers_id IS NULL

UNION

SELECT NULL, B.Name, 0
FROM business AS B
LEFT JOIN records as R ON B.id = R.business_id
WHERE r.business_id IS NULL
```

Comment: ah, you answered my question :) +1 for that

Comment: it should not be SELECT NULL, B.Name, 0 in the third part?

Answer (score 0):

User OUTER JOIN instead of the INNER JOIN to include these missing records:

```
SELECT N.mobile, B.name, count(*) as Total 
FROM records as R
 OUTER JOIN business as B ON B.id = R.business_id
 OUTER JOIN numbers as N ON N.id  = R.numbers_id 
group by N.mobile, B.name
```

Comment: The difference between Michael Frederickson and Mohammedn's result is FULL OUTER JOIN vs OUTER JOIN.  I was curious about the difference and did some reasearch.  Looks like FULL OUTER JOIN is the syntax to use.  OUTER JOIN might work but would probably be the same.  All the references I see say LEFT OUTER, RIGHT OUTER and FULL OUTER so I would go with FULL OUTER JOIN

Comment: whoa, Michael's answer disappeared!  I was about to upvote it!

Comment: @MichaelDurrant It's back now... there was a complication because MySQL doesn't actually support `FULL OUTER JOIN`...